# "body * { cursor: auto; }" after "body { cursor: pointer; }" do not reset inheritance in Opera

Tags: html, css

In Chromium and Firefox [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bQ6rW/) works as expected. But in Opera v.12.16 cursor on orange paragraph stays as hand like on the body, why? I doing something wrong?

CSS:

```
body {
   background-image: url( http://i.imgur.com/IH2QeSI.png );
   cursor: pointer;
}
body, html {
   width: 100%;
   height: 100%;
   margin: 0;
}
body * {
  cursor: auto;
}

p {
    width: 50%;
    height: 100%;
    margin:0 auto;
    background-color: orange;
}
```

HTML:

```
<body>
    <p></p>
</body>
```

Update:

In Firefox something goes wrong to when I add a link and text inside paragraph, Like this:

```
<body>
    <p><a href='xxx'>xxx</a>xxx</p>
</body>
```

On link cursor appears as "selection", you can see it in Firefox. [Updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bQ6rW/2/)

Comment: Try avoid using `*` in CSS, it can slow down the page.

Comment: Why are you using such an old version of Opera? How many people worldwide even use that?

Comment: Agree with @j08691 Even the current version (17) has less than 0.5 % of the whole market.

Comment: @Daniel Lisik, thanks for the tip. Sad to know that such elegant way have slowdown side effect. So enumeration of root elements in css will be the only right way?

Comment: @j08691, my auditory stil using even older versions of Opera :(

Comment: @user3101054 Hmm.. okay, but if you use just `*` instead of `body *`, does it work?

Comment: @user3101054 About your question, it depends. My personal opinion is that if you have a small site with not too big CSS-files, you could use `*` and not notice any performance difference. But it all depends on many different things. I personally would try to write out all the root elements that should be affected by the specific CSS rule.

Comment: @Daniel Lisik
>if you use just * instead of body *, does it work?
Nope.
And thank you for the explanation about *

Comment: in this case the * won't make the difference

Answer (score 0):

Opera doesn't support `cursor:auto`, use `cursor:default` instead :)